# how to use print both as a function and a variable in one program

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I have used print to store value like:

```
print=3
```

After then I am not able to use it to print any message:

```
print('a message')
```

Its giving error:

```
'int object is not callable'
```

Is there any way to use print both as a variable and a functions? If not then Why not python just makes built-in function names as keyword to remove this conflict?

Comment: Functions are variables *too*.

Comment: yeah very usefull as this hits me that its executing axactly same as when we assign a different value to a variable. thanx

Comment: one more thing, as this reassigning of builtin function is making conflict why not  python makes them as reserved?

Comment: see http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2013/11/story-of-none-true-false.html; because built-ins contains a large number of names, it is often fine to shadow them and it would hurt forward compatibility.

Comment: oh thats why. thanx again @Martin Pieters

Answer (score 1):

Functions and data share the same namespace in Python -- as they do in many other languages (the entire family of LISP-1s comes to mind first, including Scheme and Clojure; also Ruby, Groovy, and I'm sure many more).

Thus no, you cannot do this. Widely available checkers (pylint, pychecker, etc) will catch and report on attempts to shadow builtins (such as print) with data.

Comment: thanks for the answer @charles Duffy